# Zurb foundation Interchange with Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, zurb-foundation, foundation-interchange

Is Zurb Foundation's [Interchange](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/interchange.html) compatible for use with Django templates? I can't see a way to get them to work together, though the issue is just a technical one - Interchange seems to want html file paths, while Django's html templates render inline.

I suppose it would be possible to render the necessary templates each request into temporary files and hand those to Interchange, but that's not a very clean solution and would require a lot of boilerplate. I'm looking for a cleaner solution or for an alternative within Foundation and Django.

Comment: I don't really understand your question: Foundation's interchange works in the client (the user's browser) and will select to download the appropriate file when the browser is rendering. For each media class you want to serve a different file for, interchange needs the file's URL. Django's `{% static %}` template tag can perfectly be used to create the URLs for all the different files you want to serve.

Comment: The rendered HTMLs are dynamic. Think e.g. a a slider with some dynamic content, which has a different design (e.g. needs to load different backgrounds) for mobile and desktop.

Comment: Yes, of course, I get that. You can use interchange to load the appropriate background image for mobile and desktop, you just need django template to generate the various URLs, e.g. inside the `<img>` tag: `data-interchange="[{% static 'images/my_background_small.png' %}, small],
          [{% static 'images/my_background.png' %}, medium]` will make sure the browser only loads the appropriate background image depending if the media class is `small` or > `medium`

Comment: The entire slide's html structure is different for mobile and desktop, not just the static background files.

Answer (score 1):

No, Foundation's interchange is javascript that runs in the browser within the HTML file produced by Django on your back-end. It's meant to be used for loading static files, mostly media, dependent on the size class of your browser view. E.g. inside and `<img>` tag:

```
<img data-interchange="[{% static 'images/my_background_small.png' %}, small], [{% static 'images/my_background.png' %}, medium]>
```

If you want to serve different HTML to different types of end-devices, you have to add that logic to your Django app's view, so that it uses a different template depending on the client. In general there are a few approaches:

1. What people do nowadays: Write responsive templates so that the same
   HTML is served for mobile and desktop. For the few minor
   differences, you can hide/show divs depending on the media class.
2. Check the device in your middleware and pass it as parameter to your views and templates so you can make decisions on it. Check [django-mobile](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile) for example
3. Check the device in your server (apache or nginx) and add an HTTP header to your request that you can parse in your view (e.g. `request.META.get('HTTP_MOBILE_SITE','no')`. Example [here](http://bookofstranger.com/mobile-and-desktop-site-with-django/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try option 1 which you already mentioned in the discussion in the comments above, and see if that works well enough for my case. If not, it's good to know about django-mobile, and that Foundation's data Interchange does *not* support the full inline-html switching use case (though I don't see a real reason why it couldn't)